# Error al usar apt update en Lubuntu

Tags: linux

Al intentar actualizar apt me aparece el siguiente error. No sé si es un problema de los repositorios o de la versión de Lubuntu(19.10) ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

```
    (base) javier@javier-pc:~$ sudo apt update
    Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
    Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                         
    Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                                                                 
    Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-dev/backports-staging/ubuntu eoan InRelease
      403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
    Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
    Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                       
    Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release                                                   
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
    Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release               
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
    Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release                     
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
    Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
    Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
    Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
    E: Fallo al obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-dev/backports-staging/ubuntu/dists/eoan/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-dev/backports-staging/ubuntu eoan InRelease» no está firmado.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Comment: Cual version de lubuntu, 32 o 64 bit? "Unfortunately with main Ubuntu and Lubuntu dropping 32-bit upgrades, 32-bit upgrades after Lubuntu 18.04 are not supported."  "Ubuntu y Lubuntu no soporat upgrades de 32-bit desde version 18.04."

Comment: x86_64. 64 bits. Distribution 19.10